# Restart a service in a docker container

Tags: docker, nginx

I have a docker container that runs nginx on debian. In response to some input, I need to restart the nginx service but not the whole container. Running "service nginx restart" blows the whole container away.

Is there any way to restart a service in a docker container without restarting the whole container?

Comment: "Restarting the container" just means restarting the single process in the container; the container _is_ the service for many practical purposes.  In practice I'd always delete and recreate the container for consistency.

Answer (score 1):

You can go inside the container and restart the nginx

```
sudo docker exec –it nginx-container /bin/bash
```

Answer (score 1):

Of course it's **recommended to rebuild** the container when you do the changes, but I recommend `reload`ing the `nginx` service with either running `bash` inside of container and then reload it:

```
sudo docker exec -it NGINX_NAME bash
```

Then run `service nginx reload`.

Or:

```
sudo docker exec -it NGINX_NAME service nginx reload
```

Answer (score 0):

Since there is no direct access to the command line of the NGINX container, NGINX commands cannot be sent to a container directly. Instead, signals can be sent to a container via Docker kill command.

To reload the NGINX configuration, send the HUP signal to Docker:

```
$ docker kill -s HUP container-name
```

To restart NGINX, run this command to restart the container:

```
$ docker restart container-name
```